# Laravel returning view

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5

What is the difference between,

```
return View::make('hello');
```

and

```
return view('hello');
```

and

```
return 'hello';
```

they all produce the same output but why three syntaxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Your examples are a bit different.

`view()` is just a helper function operating just like `View::make()`. But doing it this way, you don't have to `use View;` at top of your controller (or service class) in that manner. Behind the scenes Laravel would make a view instance and populate it with the arguments that is just passed in. In your example, `hello.blade.php`.

Returning  `'hello'` is somewhat different because there is no blade file involved and the passed string is passed to the `Response` object directly.

Check out these links, especially the api. It can be very helpful.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-view

https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/View/View.html